# Android pass object between activities by reference

Tags: android, android-intent, pass-by-reference

I have an object that I pass through 2-3 activities as Parseable/Serialisable using Intents. What I want is for example when the object goes from Activity1 to Activity3

```
Activity1->Activity2->Activity3
```

and Activity3 performs some changes in the object, then Activity3 finishes and Activity2 finishes and we return to Activity1, then I want Activity1 to be aware of the changes made in Activity2 and Activity3.

Have in mind that I am not in favor of using the Singleton approach, neither the "onActivityResult" as I may need to have changes in multiple objects. I have tried to follow it using an approach with an interface that reaches to Activity3 and when changes are made it forces the previous Acitivy to update also, but it is hard to maintain it and follow it.

In iOS when you pass an object to the next view, it is by reference so changes are immediatelly available.

Any suggestions?

Comment: shared preference could help you here

Comment: @MaorHadad: SharedPreference do not support Serializable objects.

Comment: @Panos: Why not using read/write approach with a controller class?

Comment: @ Carnal: http://engineering.meetme.com/2014/03/android-tricks-and-tips-storing-a-pojo-into-shared-preferences/

Comment: @MaorHadad: Yes, of course with GSON with converts it to a String.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is run time data, it is not suggested to use sharedpreference. Create a class with name RunTimeData.java. Declare all required variables here as static. Whenever you need to save data, save it to these variables. After using the data in other class make sure you will relase the variables by setting them to null.

Example.

```
public class RunTimeData{
public static Object name=null;
}
```

While assigning data do use as follows.

```
RuntimeData.name=(Object)name;
String firstName=RunTimeData.name.getFirstName();
```

While using the data use as follows.

```
RunTimeData.name.setLastName("xxx");
RunTimeData.name=name;
```

Release the variable when you are sure that you are not going to using the value once again somewhere.

```
RunTimeData.name=null;
```

In this way you will be maintaining one object across the activities.

Comment: I think this solution explodes the OOP principles

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use one design pattern : Observer pattern

With this pattern you can notify the activity 1 when activity 2 and 3 change the object.

Some informations here :

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern
- https://andhradroid.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/object-observer-pattern-in-android/

Hopefully it solve your problem !

have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, if you pass an object as Parcelable, it will be passed by reference, and changes in one activity should be reflected in all activity containing the same reference.

However, I don't think that's a very reliable way to do it. I would suggest using `ContentProvider` and register your activity as observer for content changes.

http://www.grokkingandroid.com/use-contentobserver-to-listen-to-changes/

Comment: No. From what I see, passing an object as Parcelable does not work as passed by reference. It still creates a new instance of the object.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I used is:

In my 1st Activity i call the second using:

```
startActivityForResult(Activity2.class, MyConstants.WAITING_FOR_X_RESULT);

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    //check for updated photos
    if (requestCode == MyConstants.WAITING_FOR_X_RESULT ) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {              
            MyObject myObject = (MyObject ) data.getSerializableExtra(MyConstants.MY_OBJECT_INTENT); //get result from next activity
            this.myObject = myObject;
            notifyDatasetChanged(); //helper method to reload data
        }
    }
}
```

and in my second activity when ending I call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(MyConstants.MY_OBJECT_INTENT, myObject);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

In case the data needs to be updated also when user presses the back button to go back, don't forget to override the onBackPressed method ( do not call the super implementation ) and call the above code from there.